# Setting up SourceTree for the first time on my mac

Tags: ssh, github, sourcetree

I am trying to setup SourceTree for the first time on my MacbookPro (Monterey).

On my third screen, I got the Connect a hosted account, I clicked on [image: account connect dialog]

I picked basic, and entered my GitHub login and password, but then there is no way for me to change the default SSH Key, which is set to id_rsa.pub. I have multiple SSH keys on my mac, and I would like to enter the one I have set up for my GitHub account (github_rsa.pub).

How I do that with SourceTree?

Comment: Have you tried copying `github_rsa.pub` to `id_rsa.pub`?

Comment: How would that solve the problem? I would simply be overwriting that key, not picking another key